# wordpress changing url not opening wp-admin on click of save

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-theme

hi i tried changing the wordpress site url in generals settings from www.xyz.com/wp to www.xyz.com on click of save I amm getting following error please help

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: Have you tried reverting the changes to prove that the error disappears?

Comment: yes i have reverted but what im trying to do is change the url from www.xyz.com/wp to www.xyz.com but when i do it i get above error do i need to move the project folder to www.xyz.com ?